# Static ip on virtual box (CentOS) not is pingable from Host(windows)

Tags: virtualbox, centos-7, static-ip

i have a Virtual machine with CentOS on Virtual Box. I have configurated with nmtui a static ip:
[Like in this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKbNQ.png)

i hav restarted my network with systemctl restart netwrok.

Now from windows cmd if i type: PING 192.168.1.10 i have Session timeout.

Any Tips for me?

Thanks

Comment: the network adapter is setted to NAT

Comment: If i set Bridge i have 2 Name that i can select: 
-Intel ethernet connection I219-V;
- Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter;
but  dont work

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define virtual network for CentOS: Bridged, NAT or Local.

Try bridge mode only if the VM must be present on your LAN. Havig static IP or DHCP depends on your LAN configuration in this case.

If you want to give it a simple access to internet, use NAT mode and let it use internal DHCP of VirtualBox..

Several reasons may come up in each scenario which cause 'time out'. For example CentOS firewall may be blocking outside requests. Disable it temporarily can resolve the issue. Also check output for 'arp -a' in Windows command prompt and see if it can get MAC address of CentOS at all. If not, change and fix mode of VM network.

Comment: what you mean? "and let it use internal DHCP of VirtualBox.."

Comment: i have disabled firewalld in centos but i have still problems..

Comment: Why trying to set static address in centos whle virtualbox can provide dhcp for guest operating system?